# Node.js (Cpanel) 503 Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily busy, try again later

Tags: node.js, cpanel, es6-modules, cjs

My first attempt in deploying Node.js to cpanel has not really been funny. It turned out that `app.js` with `cjs` syntax works fine but one with `es6 module` ("type": "module" at the `package.json`) returns `"503 Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily busy, try again later!"`.

This took me couple of hours to figure out what i was doing wrong...

I will appreciate a possible solution to make a node.js with es6 module work in cpanel.

Comment: Can you add an screenshot of the resource usage?